# SLICK2D - how to re-initialize the game

Tags: java, slick2d

How can I re-initialize a game in Slick2D without using reinit() ?

If my entity is colliding with another (= game won), then I want to enter to my MainMenuState and re-initialize the game for a new game.

Comment: You should post code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your states are extending [BasicGameState](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/state/BasicGameState.html), they can extend the *enter* and the *leave* methods.

You just have to do the initialization of your "InGame" state in its *enter* method, and when your entity is colliding with another one, just do:

```
game.enterState(MainMenuState.ID, new FadeOutTransition(Color.black), new FadeInTransition(Color.black));
```

It will call the *leave* method of your InGame state.

In short, do the init of your game in the enter method, and clean the memory in the leave method (because all states are instantiated when the app is launched, you should not load your states in their constructor).